# Meaning of Harry Potter sentences

Tags: sentence-meaning

> Mrs. Dursley came into the living room carrying two cups of tea. It was no good. He'd have to say something to her. He cleared his throat nervously. "Er -- Petunia, dear -- you haven't heard from your sister lately, have you?"

I have three doubts in this paragraph

1. It was no good. -- Does it mean that the tea was not good?
2. He'd have to say something to her. -- Here what is the full form of 'He'd'? is it 'He had' or 'He would'?
3. What is the exact meaning of the sentence' He'd have to say something to her.'?

Comment: Hello, ameen. One question at a time is the rule on ELU, and your first two aren't really suitable questions on a site for linguists in any case. The third involves 'have to'; this has been covered here before.

Answer (score 3):

> Mrs. Dursley came into the living room carrying two cups of tea. It was no good. He'd have to say something to her. He cleared his throat nervously. "Er -- Petunia, dear -- you haven't heard from your sister lately, have you?"

I've replaced the original words with the meaning in bold.

> Mrs. Dursley came into the living room carrying two cups of tea. **It was no good trying to avoid the conversation**. **He would** have to say something to her. He cleared his throat nervously. "Er -- Petunia, dear -- you haven't heard from your sister lately, have you?"

1. *It was no good* means here, *The situation was bad, yet unavoidable*.
2. *He'd* = *He would*
3. Mr. Dursley would have to bring up the strange situation, and ask Mrs. Dursley if she'd heard from her cousin in an attempt to make sense of his bizarre day.

Comment: Yes and let's remember that passage is not one of JK' best, as can be seen from the confusion over what was good…

Dropping 'Mrs. Dursley came into the living room carrying two cups of tea' and starting at 'It was no good…' would hardly hurt, would it?